# При попытке переиспользовать HTTP-соединение для обработки заголовка Keep-Alive, recv зависает, читая второй звпрос от клиента

Tags: c++, http, веб-сервер, http-server

Я пишу свой небольшой HTTP-сервер. Пытаюсь ообработать заголовок Keep-Alive, чтоб можно было повтороно использовать соединение.

Я использую такой алгоритм: создаю соединение с помощью accept, читаю из него с помощью recv, обрабатываю запрос, отвечаю на него с помощью send, используя в ответе заголовок Keep-Alive, не закрыв соединение опять использую на него же recv, если recv вернуло 0, закрываю соединение. ПОдскажите что я делаю не так, и как правильно обрабатыват соединение, чтоб его можно было переиспользовать ? Зависает на любых данных второго запроса, если закрывать соединение и по новой открывать, все нормально

```
 for(;;)
    {
      client *current = client::listen_port(cone.get_socket());//здесь вызывается accept
      httpHandler worker(current);//этот класс занимается обработкой запросов, мы передаем в него указатель на объект класса, где содержится информация о клиенте
      for(;;)
      {
          httpParser* temp = new httpParser(current->get_client());// происходит вызов recv и класс httpParser анализирует запрос
          if (temp->get_recvByte() > 0)
            worker.handle(temp);//если recv что то вернул, мы обрабатываем запрос и отвечаем на него
          if (temp->get_recvByte() == 0)
              break;
          if (temp->get_recvByte())
              std::cout << "error";
          delete temp;
      }
    }
```

вот как проивходит вызов recv

```
httpParser::httpParser(int client_d)
{
    char buffer[req_buff_size];
    recvByte = recv(client_d, buffer,req_buff_size - 1, 0); // получаем сообщение из сокета
    if (recvByte > 0)
    {
        buffer[recvByte] = '\0';
        reqest = buffer;
        std::cout << reqest <<std::endl; // для тестов
        if (recvByte < 0)
           throw std::invalid_argument( "error recv\n" );

        if (reqest.find("GET") == 0)
        {
          type = GET;
          GET_parse();
        }
          else if (reqest.find("POST") == 0)
        {
          type = POST;
          POST_Parse();
        }
        else if (reqest.find("HEAD") == 0)
          type = HEAD;
        else
          throw std::invalid_argument( "invalid REQ\n" );

        requestedFile();
    }
}
```

Comment: И где конкретно (на каких данных (укажите в обновлении запроса, какие данные посылал клиент, какими отвечал сервер)) вы висните? Пока ни из текста вопроса, ни из приведенного кода это не понятно

Comment: связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1063695/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%ba-keep-alive/1063867?noredirect=1#comment1823021_1063867

Comment: Выложенного кода недостаточно, чтобы сказать в чём ошибка. Во-вторых, вы точно уверены, что клиент не закрывает соединение?

Comment: Добавьте `std::cout << "Calling recv() on socket " << client_d << std::endl;` прямо перед `recvByte = recv(client_d, buffer,req_buff_size - 1, 0);`. Посмотрите, не меняется ли значение сокета, который вы читаете.

Comment: @ВЛ80 нет, значение сокета не меняется

Comment: @ВЛ80 я не уверен, но в поступающих запросах приходит заголовок Keep-Alive, следовательно соединение не должно закрываться. Но в ответе, вместе с заголовком Keep-Alive я отправляю еще и заголовок Content_Length, с длиной тела ответа, может быть такое, что из за этого заголовка, на клиентской стороне закрывается соединение ?

Comment: @ВЛ80 хотя браузер продолжает подгрузку, несмотря на то, что recv завис

Comment: Если клиент закрывает соединение нормальным способом, ваш `recv` возвратит `0`, и вы должны вызвать `close()` на стороне сервера и закончить работу с этим соединением. А где ваш код, вызывающий `close()`?

Comment: @ВЛ80 close вызывается в диструкторе класса client, с этим нет проблем, проблема в том, что recv после первого чтения не возвращает ничего,следовательно ждет пока появится что читать, но в то время сервер уже прислал несколько запросов на отдачу контента, в одном соединении.

Comment: А что показывает ваш `std::cout << reqest <<std::endl; // для тестов`? Вы видите один запрос или несколько?

Comment: @ВЛ80 нет, приходит только один, и функция блокиурется на чтение, но должно придти несколько. Почему то recv не может прочитать второй. ПРи использовании 1 соединение - 1 запрос, приходит несколько запросов, но на каждый из них устанавливается свое соединение.