# Keep-alive может обработать в одном соединении только часть запросов

Tags: c, http, http-server

Пишу свой http-сервер, потребовалось переиспользовать соединение с помощью keep-alive. Я пытаюсь добиться того, чтоб статические запросы обрабатывались в одном соединении и в одном процессе. Пробоема в том, что хоть соединение переиспользуется, и в одном процессе последовательно обрабатывается несколько запросов, пришедших от одного клиента, сервер все равно не может обработать все запросы. Сервер обрабатывает по несколько запросов в нескольких процессах. Когда один из процессов отдает клиенту последнюю информацию, клиент закрывает соединение, и во всех процессах recv возвращает 0, тогда сервер закрывает соединение. Если использовать один процесс(не вызывать fork), то recv блокируется на чтение, обработав несколько запросов, при этом браузер не заканчивает что то подгружать, следовательно соединение не зкарыто.

Почему так происходит? Как добиться желаемого результата?

Вот функция, в которой происходит обработка:

```
void respond(int n)
{
    char mesg[99999], *reqline[3], data_to_send[BYTES], path[99999];
    int rcvd, fd, bytes_read;
    int count = 0;
    do
    {
        rcvd=recv(clients[n], mesg, 99999-1, 0);
        count++;
        printf("prohod: %d\n", count);
    if (rcvd<0)    // receive error
        fprintf(stderr,("recv() error\n"));
    else if (rcvd==0)    // receive socket closed
        fprintf(stderr,"Client disconnected upexpectedly.\n");
    else    // message received
    {
        mesg[rcvd] = 0;
        printf("process: %d\n", n);
        printf("%s", mesg);
        reqline[0] = strtok (mesg, " \t\n");
        if ( strncmp(reqline[0], "GET\0", 4)==0 )
        {
            reqline[1] = strtok (NULL, " \t");
            reqline[2] = strtok (NULL, " \t\n");
            if ( strncmp( reqline[2], "HTTP/1.0", 8)!=0 && strncmp( reqline[2], "HTTP/1.1", 8)!=0 )
            {
                write(clients[n], "HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request\r\n\r\n", 25);
            }
            else
            {
                if ( strncmp(reqline[1], "/\0", 2)==0 )
                    reqline[1] = "/index.html";        //Because if no file is specified, index.html will be opened by default (like it happens in APACHE...

                strcpy(path, ROOT);
                strcpy(&path[strlen(ROOT)], reqline[1]);
                printf("file: %s\n", path);

                if ( (fd=open(path, O_RDONLY))!=-1 )    //FILE FOUND
                {
                    static const char hdr[]=
                        "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n"
                        "Connection: keep-alive\r\n"
                        "Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=1000\r\n";

                    send(clients[n], hdr , sizeof(hdr)-1, 0);
                    size_t f_sz = fd_size(fd);
                    printf("%lu\n",f_sz);
                    sprintf (data_to_send, "Content-length: %lu\r\n", f_sz);
                    write (clients[n], data_to_send, strlen(data_to_send));
                    send(clients[n], "\r\n" , 2, 0);

                    while ( (bytes_read=read(fd, data_to_send, BYTES))>0 )
                    {
                        write (clients[n], data_to_send, bytes_read);
                    }
                } else {
                    static const char msg[] = "HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found\r\n"
                        "Connection: keep-alive\r\n"
                        "Content-length: 0\r\n"
                        "\r\n";
                    write(clients[n], msg, sizeof(msg)-1); //FILE NOT FOUND
                }
            }
        }
     }
    }while(rcvd != 0);

    //Closing SOCKET
    shutdown (clients[n], SHUT_RDWR);         //All further send and recieve operations are DISABLED...
    close(clients[n]);
    clients[n]=-1;
}
```

все это крутится в цикле:

```
while (1)
    {
        addrlen = sizeof(clientaddr);
        clients[slot] = accept (listenfd, (struct sockaddr *) &clientaddr, &addrlen);

        if (clients[slot]<0)
            error ("accept() error");
        else
        {
            if (fork() == 0)
            {
                respond(slot);
                _exit(0);
            }
        }

        while (clients[slot]!=-1) slot = (slot+1)%CONNMAX;
    }
```

Этот код является тестировочным, и взят отсюда

http://dpaste.com/2104P0V

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1063695/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%ba-keep-alive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Если использовать один процесс(не вызывать fork), то recv блокируется на чтение, обработав несколько запросов, при этом браузер не заканчивает что то подгружать, следовательно соединение не зкарыто.

Это связано с тем как работает браузер. Для большинства браузеров при настройках по умолчанию в данном случае происходит примерно следующее:

1. Браузер создаёт соединение (`connect()`), сервер его принимает (`accept()`) и начинает ждать запроса (в `recv()`). Получает его, отправляет в ответ html-страничку и начинает ждать следующего.
2. Браузер получает страничку и пытается загрузить весь контент (картинки, css, скрипты), которые на ней есть. При этом первую «картинку» он будет загружать по тому же соединению, а также одновременно с этим попытается **создать ещё несколько соединений**, чтобы загружать всё параллельно, а изначальное **не будет закрыто** даже после загрузки.
3. Сервер обработает все запросы по уже открытому соединению и продолжет ждать на нём новых, но т.к. управление не дойдёт до `accept()`, то все попытки создать новые соединения браузером просто повиснут в ожидании.

В итоге имеем тупик:

- Сервер ждёт запросов на уже созданном соединении.
- Клиент ждёт ответа на попытки создания новых соединений.

> Как добиться желаемого результата?

Одно из:

- Оставить многопоточность на месте.
- Переделать всё в полноценный однопоточный сервер (опять же, смотри системные вызовы семейства `poll()`/`select()`).
- Отказаться от `keep-alive`.
- Настроить клиента так, чтобы он не создавал доп. соединений/закрывал существующие. Например, для `firefox` см. параметры в `about::config`:

  - `network.http.max-persistent-connections-per-server`
  - `network.http.max-connections`
  - `network.http.tcp_keepalive.long_lived_connections`

Comment: Получается, это нормальное поведение при использовании keep-alive? Можно ли использовать epoll wait для решения проблемы с ожиданием ?

Comment: @DenverToha, да, нормальное... об этом я уже говорю с прошлого года ;). Да можно воспользоваться и epoll'ом, но я бы советовал всё же сначала разобраться со стандартными вариантами — `poll()` или `select()`.